# Why use source option in javac

Tags: java, javac

I understand what source option does, but I don't understand why would someone want to use that.

According to Oracle Docs:

> -source: Specifies the version of source code accepted.

> Source option restricts the features one can use, for example, -source 1.5 means the compiler accepts features introduced in JDK 5.

I read some article, some point out target and source options are used for backwards compatible. But since backwards compatibility is about jre's version and bytecode's version, shouldn't target option can solely solve this problem?

Then what's the meaning of using source option. Is there any good reason to restrict source code version?

Answer (score 1):

The `-source` option is obsolete; whilst there are reasons to set `--source` and `--target` (all options now have double dashes, too - the single dash variants are also obsolete) separately, these are extremely exotic. Hence, there's the new `--release` option which is more or less equivalent to setting  both source and target.

There are 3 options relevant for compatibility:

- `--source` controls what java lang features you are allowed to use. This option doesn't actually work, in the sense that the java lang spec does not cover multiple versions, and `javac` does not actually ship with 10 separate parsers. In effect it more or less causes javac to explicitly mark certain new constructs as invalid, though the parser does know what they mean.
- `--target` controls the class file format version. Eventhough at various times java has gained source features that just compile down to 'ordinary' bytecode (not to some newly introduced bytecode construct without which the language feature cannot be compiled into a class file), source level higher than target level (e.g. `-source 17 -target 16`) has never worked - your target option has to be at least as high as the source option. Various transpilers and plugins have existed at various times to bolt this rather useful functionality onto javac.
- But those 2 together still aren't enough: there's also the core library (essentially, the classes whose package names start with `java.`) - java15 might introduce some new classes which means if you use them, and then compile that with `javac -source 14 -target 14` (or without using these obsolete switches, `javac --release 14`), it might well compile fine, but wouldn't *actually* run on a JDK release 14, due to the class files not being there. You could fix this by setting the bootclasspath of the compiler itself, though this means you need a JDK14 installed for the benefits of having access to a JVM14 version of the core libs to compile against.

Thus, to answer your question: You always set it **together** with `-target`, because `-target` on its own does not actually imply 'different source level'. This is kinda silly, and that's why `-target` and `-source` have been replaced by `--release`. Secondly, why would one want to restrict `--release` to a lower version? To ensure the class files you end up with also run on a lower version. This can be rather important if, for example, you're releasing a library that other programmers will fetch as dependency and start to use.

Comment: "In effect it more or less causes javac to explicitly mark certain new constructs as invalid" What does constructs mean in this context?

Comment: Say, you use switch-as-expression and compile that with javac17, passing `--source 11`. Then your switch-as-expression won;t compile; it wasn't valid java syntax in java11.

Comment: Doesn't that mean --source option work?  Since javac can judge whether is valid syntax or not.

Comment: It works, but the option isn't exactly "parse source files precisely as JDK11's javac would". It simply means: "Parse it as JDK17's javac, which you are, would - but then mark off any constructs introduced after 11". You can write source code that compiles on JDK11's javac, and won't with JDK17's javac passing `--source 11`. It'll be very exotic weird stuff, as java tries to be backwards compatible, but you can do it. A proper source option would mean that wasn't possible.

Comment: That's really a weird behavior. Can you give me some sorce code example that can compile on JDK11's yet can't with JDK17's javac passing --source 11.

Comment: Besides that, does --release have the same problem? As far as I understand,  release = source + target + bootclasspath, so it should  have the same problem as  --source?

Comment: Yes, `--release` would have the same problem. Try to use `javax.Generated`, or even 'anything in javafx', that'll fail on JDK17 (unless you add the requisite deps). For language features, there was an issue with accessing private members of a subtype. (`class A { private void foo() {} void test() { B b = new B(); b.foo(); }} class B extends A{}`), I think that was something that worked on 6 and didn't on 8, and `javac --source 6` on JDK8's javac wouldn't fix that.

Comment: Just want to say thank you for all of these! So informative and easy to understand! Now I know so many things I didn't know before :]

Answer (score -2):

It's sometimes necessary for applications to ensure their code is backward compatible with an older version of Java. The target and source options in javac make it easy to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, but what's the point of restricting source code version? Target option can solely solve  backward compatible.

Comment: Because it older version and tha javac has that easy source option to proceed